# Help with Layout

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a profile page for a network...similar to Facebook profile page. I need the background the tabs are on to go under the profile photo on the left...so when the user updates their status it grows vertically underneath the photo..take a look at Facebook profile page. I've tried placing the status at the top "topStatus" with position: absolute; top: -51px; on the left column "profile_leftside" which works but when more apps are added to the left side it displays past the bottom border..doesn't stay contained in "pageContent".

Basically here's my layout...

```
<div id="pageContent">

<div id="topStatus">
<div id="innerStatus">
*STATUS AND TABS HERE // EXPANDS VERTICALLY WHEN STATUS IS UPDATED*
</div>
</div>

<div id="profileContent">

<div id="profile_leftside">
*LEFT SIDE APPS*
</div>

<div id="profile_rightside">
*TAB CONTENT*
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pageContent {
  width: 799px;
  min-height:600px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float:left;
  border-left:1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-right:1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom:1px solid #b3b3b3;
}
#topStatus {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;
  width: 100%;
}
#innerStatus {
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 225px;
   }
#profileContent {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 10px;
}
#profile_leftside {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
}
#profile_rightside {
  float: right;
  width: 580px;
}
```

Just trying to get "profile_leftside" at the top left without breaking the content at the bottom. Maybe theres a better way to lay this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the profile_left to overlap the statusbar at the top that spans across the container or do you want it to stay below the statusbar?

Answer (score 0):

I've always found CSS frameworks to be very helpful.  Many of them have been proven again and again, and it takes abstracts you up a layer above having to worry about specific CSS layout problems.

I've used Blueprint CSS for many things, but have also heard good things of the 960 Grid system.

Blueprint CSS:  http://www.blueprintcss.org/
960 Grid System:  http://960.gs/

Regards,
Chris

Comment: @ snkmchnb - Yes I want the profile_leftside to overlap the top status area. I positioned it absolute 51px as it holds it in position. I've tried using a negative margin top on the leftside but it moves when the status is updated, just want the status area to expand vertically..exactly like Facebook. Maybe I should lay this out different, this seemed like the most logical way.

Comment: @ Chrisc - Thanks for the tip! I'll do some reading up on Blueprint tho I'd just like to find a quick fix for this. :)

Comment: Of if you don't use a framework, use at least a css reset some kind (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to add any CSS problems to JSFIDDLE.NET so other people can look at the problem directly. I've added it for you and come up with a solution that I think you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/SqxN7/12/

The top bar now expands with the left Apps. I had to reorganize the placement of the div's and add 'overflow: auto' to the top status bar to allow it to expand as the app bar is a float.